# How to change language in MB_OKCANCEL buttons text (Windows API) using MessageBoxExW with Python?

Tags: python-2.7, winapi, button, translation, messagebox

I have an application which shows a window with two buttons (Ok and Cancel), I was using it in English, but now I want to show Ok and Cancel button's text in Chinese.

My original code was:

```
if win32con.IDOK == win32gui.MessageBox(self.hwnd,self.dic.voc["mainwin.quitConfirm"],
                                       self.dic.voc["mainwin.quitConfirmTitle"],
                                       win32con.MB_OKCANCEL):
```

And now I am trying with `MessageBoxExW` function, because in the API page says you can use any language in the last parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxexw).

So now my code is as follows:

```
lang = win32api.MAKELANGID(4, 2)
if win32con.IDOK ==ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxExW(self.hwnd,self.dic.voc["mainwin.quitConfirm"], self.dic.voc["mainwin.quitConfirmTitle"], win32con.MB_YESNO, lang):
```

But it continues showing the text buttons in English, not in Chinese, I have also set in my computer, in Region and Language, Chinese(Simplified, PRC) in 'Formats' and in 'System Locale'. 
And my script is encoded as 'UTF-8'.

When I run this,

```
locale.getdefaultlocale(["LANGUAGE"])
```

I obtain,

```
('zh_CN', 'cp936')
```

I would appreciate very much any help or clue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Luisa, it works for me on Windows 10. Does it work for you on Windows 7?

Comment: Thank you very much Rita. Now it still not works because I need to install first a LIP in order to see the Display Language section, under keyboards and languages in region and language in control panel, and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows 10, you need to install a language pack in Windows for the specified language.

It does NOT have to be the default displayed language, but it needs to be in the installed language packs.

[image]

Comment: I am actually using Windows 7, I supposed the same applies for this version.

Comment: Thank you very much EyIM. The case is that I am trying to install the language package for Windows 7 but in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages, it doesn't appear the option Display language, Install/uninstall languages. In Windows help it says that: the Display language section will only be visible if you have already installed an LIP. What do I have to do to install it? Thank you.

Comment: Check this post: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972813/windows-7-language-packs-are-available-for-computers-that-are-running

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help!

In the end I could installed the language package I needed using an app called Vistalizator, because I don't have MUI as I am using Windows 7 Professional (and I couldn't installed it via Microsoft Updates). You only need this app and the language package for the Windows version you are using; you can download both from the same page (https://www.froggie.sk/es/details.html).

In the app you select the downloaded exe file which contains the language package, you change to Express mode and follow the app steps.

At last I can see the text buttons in the language I need and using the MessageBoxExW function, it works! I'm really grateful for your help.